# Creating zip file with php

Tags: php, joomla, zip

I am creating a zip file of a particular folder, I am using joomla 1.5 version in which i have a component of form submission and I want to create a zip file with submitted documents. On my localhost, its creating the zip file, when I test to remote server, It replaces the extension with some kind of a number, suppose we are creating a file test.zip, but its creating like this test.zip.a12345 and test.zip.b12345..
The code which I have used to create zip file:

```
$files = array(
    'files/file1.jpg',
    'files/file2.jpg',
    'files/file3.jpg'
);


$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = "zipfile.zip";
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

foreach($files as $file){
    $zip->addFile($file);
}

$zip->close();
```

and the output on local server is zipfile.zip
output on live server is : zipfile.zip.a11236 and zipfile.zip.b11236

Comment: You checked the file name in FTP , or how do you know the file name ? Asking as your code does not show how do you reveal your file name

Comment: This code is just snippet .. I used the folder path like this 
 $filepath = JPATH_BASE.'\\images\\foldername\\'

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the ZipArchive::OVERWRITE flag when opening the file.

It chooses another name because the file already exists?

See: http://php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php

Comment: but its creating on local server with this

Comment: Yes, I know. But you ZipArchive::CREATE over an existing file. That cannot be, so a new name is made up by ZipArchive. Just test this by creating a non-existing file.

Comment: the problem is that its not creating zip file,, its creating another extension's file which is not useful for me